# Django doesn't load a static file

Tags: jquery, django

I'm making a plugin for django-cms, I created first the web page in pure HTML, Javascript and CSS way and it worked perfectly, but while I'm trying to make it work on django-cms it seems it doesn't load a the jquery-ui and therefore breaking my BoarGUIFunctionality.js script and my application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

{% load staticfiles %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery-ui.min.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/Board.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.simple.timer.js" %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/jquery-ui.min.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/boardStyle.css" %}">
<body>
<div id="FirstModal"><p>¿Desea comenzar su turno?</p></div>
<div id="SecondModal"><p>¿Qué tipo de turno desea comenzar?</p></div>
<div id="ConfirmationModal"><p>¿Esta seguro que desea realizar esa jugada?</p></div>
<div id="FinishTurnModal"><p>¿Desea terminar su turno?</p></div>
<div id="FinishedTurnModal">Turno Finalizado</div>
<div id="boardContainer">
    <div id="right">
        <p id="dice1"></p><p id="dice2"></p> 
        <button id="diceRoller" class="no-display">Lanzar Dados</button>
    </div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <button id="movePlayerPieces" class="no-display">Mover fichas jugador</button>
    <button id="finishTurn" class="no-display">Finalizar Turno</button>
    <div id ="scoreContainer">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="blackPlayerScore"></td><td id="whitePlayerScore"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="blackPlayerName"></td><td id="whitePlayerName"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p id="timer"></p>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var board = new Board();
    board.setGamePhase(1);
    board.setPlayerTurn('Someone');
    board.setBlackPlayer("Kevin");
    board.setWhitePlayer("Someone");
    board.setInitiatorGamePlayer("Kevin");
    var pieces = {
        black : ["a5","d7","f2","c6","e4","i4"],
        white : ["r3","h4","b9","g5","j2","k9"],
    };
    board.setBallPosition("g9");
    board.setTimeTimer("12-06-2015 09:00:00");
    board.setGoalWhite(0);
    board.setGoalBlack(0);
    board.setPiecesPosition(pieces);
    board.buildBoard("left");
    session = 'Someone';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/BoardGUIFunctionality.js" %}"></script>
</html>
```

by the way I wrapped inside $(function(){ ... }) the code of BoardUIFunctionality. On settings.py STATIC_URL has the value of /static/, so I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: **STATIC_ROOT**, **STATICFILES_FINDERS**, **STATICFILES_DIRS** ?

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'proyectohdp', 'static'),
)

There is no STATICFILES_FINDERS setting, in settings.py, by the way proyectohdp is the name of the folder where my plugin is

Comment: are you getting 404 for jquery ui?

Comment: no it loads the file, and as I said above when I run my scripts and pure HTML, Javascript and CSS it works without problems but when I do it in django server it shows me: [link](http://postimg.org/image/yd35sus55/), here it loads jquery-ui file : [link](http://postimg.org/image/3lc2oe5s7/)